# Kernel density plot in R, plot discreet values on map for specific grid cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I am trying to highlight single 1x1 degree grid squares on a map.

It works highlighting individual grid squares for the first 1 squares but after highlight the 4th square it begins to highlight multiple groups of squares and I am not sure why?

```
library(ggOceanMaps)
#devtools::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/ggOceanMapsData")
library(ggOceanMapsData)

dt <- data.frame(lon = c(35, 35, 60, 60), lat = c(-25, -25, -40, -40))

grid_2019_1 <- data.frame(lat=c(-28, -29), long=c(51, 52))
grid_2019_2 <- data.frame(lat=c(-28, -29), long=c(52, 53))
grid_2019_3 <- data.frame(lat=c(-28, -29), long=c(53, 54))
grid_2019_4 <- data.frame(lat=c(-30, -31), long=c(41, 42))
grid_2019_5 <- data.frame(lat=c(-30, -31), long=c(42, 43))

P4 = basemap(data = dt,bathymetry = T,
        lon.interval = 1,
        lat.interval = 1,
        bathy.style = "contour_blues",
        bathy.border.col = NA,
        bathy.size = 0.1,
        bathy.alpha = 1) 

P4.1 = P4 + stat_density2d(data = grid_2019_1, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = ..density..),
                    geom = 'tile', contour = F) 
P4.2 = P4.1 + stat_density2d(data = grid_2019_2, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = ..density..),
                           geom = 'tile', contour = F) 
P4.3 = P4.2 + stat_density2d(data = grid_2019_3, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = ..density..),
                           geom = 'tile', contour = F) 

P4.4 = P4.3 + stat_density2d(data = grid_2019_4, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = ..density..),
                           geom = 'tile', contour = F) 
P4.5 = P4.4 + stat_density2d(data = grid_2019_5, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = ..density..),
                           geom = 'tile', contour = F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one `geom_density2d` (contour or filled) then `ggplot` seems to draw all of them over the union of their extents. Here's an example with two data sets, one in (0,1)x(0,1) and the other in (2,3)x(2,3).

```
d1 = data.frame(x=runif(100,0,1), y= runif(100,0,1))
d2 = data.frame(x=runif(100,2,3), y= runif(100,2,3))
ggplot() + geom_density2d_filled(data=d2, aes(x=x,y=y)) 
   + geom_density2d_filled(data=d1, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

[image]

This is only showing d1, but extends to the extent of d2 also.

If you do this the other way round (geom for d1 then d2) you see d2 and the extent reaches to d1:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is outputting both geoms and we can only see one, or if it is overriding the first geom with the second and there's no trace of the first density in the output object. Either way, I can't find a way to crop the density to its extent to find out if we can see another one underneath it.

[a few minutes later edit:]

I think it is putting both layers but we only see the top one. If you do:

```
ggplot() + 
   geom_density2d_filled(data=d1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
   geom_point(data=d1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
   geom_point(data=d2, aes(x=x, y=y))
```

you see the density extended to the range of the points and the points over the top. Technically the density extends to +/-infinity in all directions and I don't see any way to crop it at a given extent, so ggplot just extends it to the range of all data and geoms.

I think the fix might be to compute the smoothed grids first (using `kde2d`) and then adding those as raster geoms, or dropping all the ggplot stuff and using something else like `tmap` (except you'd have to sort out all the oceanic package stuff if you really want to use that).